# Pandas - Merge rows that took two rows in document

Tags: python, pandas

I'm account statements with tabula and getting a pandas `DataFrame` object that contains extracted data from the document. Some records are spanning to two rows because of the long description. I need to merge them into one for future processing.

This is an example of such data:

```
| Description                 | Withdrawals | Deposits |
| --------------------------- | ----------- | -------- |
| e-Transfer - Autodeposit    |             |          |
|                   AF6hdfUdV |             | 17.45    |
| Credit Card Payment         |  46.78      |          |
```

The first of the two rows has only a description. The next row has a description that needs to be merged with the first row.

I tried various `groupby` but can't figure out the working parameters for my case. Is there a way to do that without iterating over rows?

Comment: Is there no transaction ID, or any other ID that would allow to know that's the same transaction?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This data parsed from pdf statement.

Comment: Can we assume that no values in both Withdrawls and Deposits columns means they need to be merged with the row below?

Comment: Can you post your code that you tried?

Comment: @CeliusStingher My plan was to match rows for merge by description, but no values in deposit and withdrawal is true as well.

Comment: @Naruto There is nothing to show, unfortunately. I played with groupby but no code to show.

Comment: How about the text being long enough for 3 rows? Or 4?

Comment: @CeliusStingher You were right, after processing statements for two years I found records that span 3 or more rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a solution under assumptions:

1. first row from the two in need of merge doesn't have any withdrawals or deposits
2. all other rows have either deposit or withdrawal (or both)

Mock dataframe creation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Description": ["AAA", "bbb", "CCC", "DDD", "eee", "FFF"],
    "Withdrawals": [None, None, 46.78, None, None, 98.3],
    "Deposits": [None, 17.45, None, None, 4.56, None]
})
df
```

Output:

```
  Description  Withdrawals  Deposits
0         AAA          NaN       NaN
1         bbb          NaN     17.45
2         CCC        46.78       NaN
3         DDD          NaN       NaN
4         eee          NaN      4.56
5         FFF        98.30       NaN
```

Some technical calculations that will allow us to track lines that need to be merged. `is_empty_value` marks the rows where no withdrawals or deposits were mentioned - the rows that need to be merged with the next one. The idea behind `change_group` is: if two subsequent rows have different values - they need to be merged. The rows woth the same number are regular rows.

```
df["is_empty_value"] = df[["Withdrawals", "Deposits"]].isna().all(axis=1)
df["change_group"] = df["is_empty_value"][::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Predicting a transaction id based on the number of the row and the number in `change_group`. This is not a natural `pandas` operation, so can be slower on large datasets.

```
def get_transaction_id(idxs, change_groups):
    transaction_ids = [idxs[0]]
    for idx, group, prev_group in zip(idxs[1:], change_groups[1:], change_groups[:-1]):
        if group != prev_group:
            transaction_ids.append(transaction_ids[-1])
        else:
            transaction_ids.append(idx)
    return transaction_ids

df["transaction_id"] = get_transaction_id(df["index"], df["change_group"])
```

Finally getting the result dataframe by grouping transactions and applying appropriate aggregation functions for each column:

```
df[["transaction_id", "Description", "Withdrawals", "Deposits"]] \
    .groupby("transaction_id") \
    .agg({
        "Description": lambda x: " ".join(x),
        "Withdrawals": sum,
        "Deposits": sum,
    }) \
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
  Description  Withdrawals  Deposits
0     AAA bbb         0.00     17.45
1         CCC        46.78      0.00
2     DDD eee         0.00      4.56
3         FFF        98.30      0.00
```

Comment: If it would be possible to accept both answers, I would also accept your answer.

Comment: Your solution works for the case with more than two consecutive rows. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Description': ['e-Transfer - Autodeposit', 'AF6hdfUdV', 'Credit Card Payment'],
    'Withdrawals': [np.nan, np.nan, 46.78],
    'Deposits': [np.nan, 17.45, np.nan],
})

mask = df['Withdrawals'].isna() & df['Deposits'].isna()

df.loc[mask, 'Description'] += ' ' + df['Description'].shift(-1)
df.loc[mask, ['Withdrawals', 'Deposits']] = df.shift(-1).loc[mask, ['Withdrawals', 'Deposits']]

df = df[~mask.shift().fillna(False)].reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.fillna('0')

print(df)
```

Result I got was:

```
                          Description Withdrawals Deposits
0  e-Transfer - Autodeposit AF6hdfUdV           0    17.45
1                 Credit Card Payment       46.78        0
```

Comment: Is it possible to extend this approach if the description is split into more than two rows?